# Include MS-Word document in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

In addtion to the documented C source code I would like to include a MS-Word document about the software architecture to the HTML doucumentation generated by Doxygen.

How can I achive this?
Is there a way to convert the MS-Wordfile *.docx to a Doxygenfile *.dox?

Answer (score 0):

You could link to the document using

```
<a href="your_doc.docx">link name</a>
```

in a comment block.

Alternative is to convert it to a (simple enough) HTML file, so that doxygen can parse that, but then you probably loose a lot of the document's markup and layout.